# appium issue, not able to launch two apps

Tags: selenium, appium

I am not able to launch two apps in single script using APPIUM, it shows error as

> An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
>   The desired should not include both of an 'appPackage' and a
>   'browserName'

```
public class SalesLeadProg { 
  public AndroidDriver<MobileElement> driver;
  private WebElement element; public WebDriverWait wait;

  @BeforeMethod 
  public void setup() throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException { 
    DOMConfigurator.configure("log4j.xml");
    DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities(); 
    caps.setCapability("automationName", "UiAutomator2"); 
    caps.setCapability("deviceName", "sunil");
    caps.setCapability("udid", "422b21e7");
    caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android"); 
    caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "8.1.0"); 
    caps.setCapability("appPackage", "com.mfcwl.mfc_dealer"); 
    caps.setCapability("appActivity", "com.mfcwl.mfc_dealer.Activity.SplashActivity"); 
    caps.setCapability("autoAcceptAlerts", true); 
    caps.setCapability("noReset", true); 
    caps.setCapability("browserName", "Chrome"); 
    //it will launch the chrome browser in mobile 
    caps.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, true); 
    ChromeOptions options=new ChromeOptions(); 
    options.setExperimentalOption("androidPackage", "com.android.chrome");
     caps.setCapability("autoGrantPermissions", true);
    // to allow the permission of contacts camara, which comes in the begining when we install the app*/ 
     caps.setCapability("unicodeKeyboard", true);
   // to make the keyboard working 
   caps.setCapability("resetKeyboard", false); 
   // it 
   try { 
       driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement> (new URL("0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"),caps); 
  }
  catch(MalformedURLException e) { 
    System.out.println(e); 
  } 
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(16, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
} 

@Test 
public void Dashboard() throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException { 
 MobileElement email = driver.findElement(By.id("com.mfcwl.mfc_dealer:id/email")); 
 Thread.sleep(4000); 
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10); 
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(email)); 
 boolean isElementPresent = email.isDisplayed(); 
 System.out.println(isElementPresent); 
 Thread.sleep(4000); 
 driver.findElementById("com.mfcwl.mfc_dealer:id/email").clear();
 driver.findElementById("com.mfcwl.mfc_dealer:id/email").sendKeys("prestige");
 System.out.println("Entered ID");

driver.findElement(By.id("com.mfcwl.mfc_dealer:id/password")).clear(); 
driver.findElement(By.id("com.mfcwl.mfc_dealer:id/password")).sendKeys("Mahindra"); 
System.out.println("Entered Password"); 
driver.findElement(By.id("com.mfcwl.mfc_dealer:id/email_sign_in_button")).click(); 
//to login 
System.out.println("Signed IN");
Thread.sleep(4000); 
 driver.findElement(By.id("com.mfcwl.mfc_dealer:id/homeTab")).click();
//to click on home button 
 System.out.println("Clicked on Home button"); 
 Thread.sleep(3000); //Set ChromeDriver location 
 System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./ChromeDriver/chromedriver.exe");
 driver.get("google.com/");   driver.findElement(By.id("com.mfcwl.mfc_dealer:id/click_lead")).click(); 

 System.out.println("Clicked on Today's follow up leads section");     
driver.findElement(By.id("com.mfcwl.mfc_dealer:id/lead_filter")).click();
```

Please assist with a solution on how to use two apps in APPIUM with a single script.

Comment: Please find my whole query:

Comment: as I am new to this site, request you to please update me in case of any mis-communication

Comment: public class SalesLeadProg {
 
 public AndroidDriver<MobileElement> driver;
 private WebElement element;
 public WebDriverWait wait;
       
    @BeforeMethod
       public void setup() throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {
      
      DOMConfigurator.configure("log4j.xml");
           
           DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
           caps.setCapability("automationName", "UiAutomator2");
           caps.setCapability("deviceName", "sunil");
           caps.setCapability("udid", "422b21e7");

Comment: caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
           caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "8.1.0");
           caps.setCapability("appPackage", "com.mfcwl.mfc_dealer");
           caps.setCapability("appActivity", "com.mfcwl.mfc_dealer.Activity.SplashActivity");
           caps.setCapability("autoAcceptAlerts", true);
           caps.setCapability("noReset", true);
           caps.setCapability("browserName", "Chrome"); //it will launch the chrome browser in mobile
           caps.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, true);

Comment: ChromeOptions options=new ChromeOptions();
           options.setExperimentalOption("androidPackage", "com.android.chrome");
           caps.setCapability("autoGrantPermissions", true);  // to allow the permission of contacts camara, which comes in the begining when we install the app*/
           caps.setCapability("unicodeKeyboard", true);  // to make the keyboard working
           caps.setCapability("resetKeyboard", false); // it 
           try
           {
            
          driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement> (new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"),caps);
           }

Comment: catch(MalformedURLException e)
           {
            System.out.println();
           }
            
           driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(16, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
     @Test
           public void Dashboard() throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {
           
            MobileElement email = driver.findElement(By.id("com.mfcwl.mfc_dealer:id/email"));
      
      Thread.sleep(4000);

Comment: WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
             
       wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(email));
             
       boolean isElementPresent = email.isDisplayed();
             
       System.out.println(isElementPresent);
       
       Thread.sleep(4000);
       
       driver.findElementById("com.mfcwl.mfc_dealer:id/email").clear();
             
       driver.findElementById("com.mfcwl.mfc_dealer:id/email").sendKeys("prestige");
       
       System.out.println("Entered ID");

Comment: driver.findElement(By.id("com.mfcwl.mfc_dealer:id/password")).clear();
       driver.findElement(By.id("com.mfcwl.mfc_dealer:id/password")).sendKeys("Mahindra");
       
       
       System.out.println("Entered Password");
     
      driver.findElement(By.id("com.mfcwl.mfc_dealer:id/email_sign_in_button")).click(); //to login
      
      System.out.println("Signed IN");
      
      Thread.sleep(4000);
      
      driver.findElement(By.id("com.mfcwl.mfc_dealer:id/homeTab")).click(); //to click on home button
      
      System.out.println("Clicked on Home button");

Comment: Thread.sleep(3000);
      
      //Set ChromeDriver location
            
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./ChromeDriver/chromedriver.exe");
      
            driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
        
      driver.findElement(By.id("com.mfcwl.mfc_dealer:id/click_lead")).click();
  
      System.out.println("Clicked on Today's follow up leads section");
  
      driver.findElement(By.id("com.mfcwl.mfc_dealer:id/lead_filter")).click();

Comment: System.out.println("Clicked on Filter");
  
      driver.findElement(By.id("com.mfcwl.mfc_dealer:id/chfollowtoday")).click();
  
      System.out.println("Clicked on Today check box");
  
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='APPLY']")).click();
  
      Thread.sleep(2000);
  
  }
}

Comment: THIS IS MY WHOLE PROGRAM, REQUEST YOU ALL TO PLEASE GIVE THE SCRIPT OR SOLUTION HOW TO USE TWO APPS IN APPIUM WITH SINGLE SCRIPT

Comment: in the future please edit your question and add new information directly into the question instead of adding comments.